# Xamarin Pair to Mac error installing Broker - ScpClient lost connection

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ssh.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 and I'm setting up a new Mac build host for others to use to build our Xamarin iOS project. I've been using my own work-issued Mac build host for years to build this project and that is still working fine.

Pair to Mac has connected to the Mac just fine to install Mono and Xamarin.iOS, but fails to install the Broker. (Screenshot at the bottom.)

The Visual Studio log shows an error that the SSH.NET ScpClient used by Xamarin is losing connection transferring Broker.zip from the VS program files directory to /tmp/ on the Mac. The file transfer is working enough to copy exactly 16,384 bytes of the file to the Mac before the connection is reset every single time. Broker.zip is bigger than 16KB, and there's a bunch of files at the destination directory exactly 16,384 bytes in size created at times corresponding to every time I've encountered this error.

I can reproduce the issue by attempting to SCP the file to the Mac myself manually in Command Prompt. Files less than 16KB transfer fine, but transfers larger than 16KB have this issue every time. I don't have this issue transferring files the exact same way to my original Mac build host. I created a question over in SuperUser for that [here (link)](https://superuser.com/questions/1612285), but nobody has jumped on it with an obvious answer.

So, I'm wondering if anyone in the Stack Overflow community has any Xamarin and Mac Build host knowledge and experience I can use to help me solve this problem? I need to get this Mac build host working for two new developers on this project.

Errors in the Pair to Mac Window:

```
An error occurred while trying to start the Broker...
An error occurred while installing Broker 16.8.000.260
```

And from the Visual Studio log:

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingScpClient|Error|0|An error occurred while using the SCP Client. Details: Client not connected.
```

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService|Error|0|An error occurred while trying to start the Broker...
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Starting connection to '10.240.0.25'...
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Server State transition from ConnectingState to DisconnectingState on 10.240.0.25 (10.240.0.25)
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Starting disconnection from 10.240.0.25...
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Starting disconnection from 10.240.0.25...
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Server State transition from DisconnectingState to DisconnectedState on 10.240.0.25 (10.240.0.25)
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|The connection to '10.240.0.25' has been finished
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Error|0|An error occurred while trying to start the Broker...
```

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.Exceptions.AgentInstallationException: An error occurred while installing Broker 16.8.000.260 ---> Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingException: Unable to copy file 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\professional\common7\ide\extensions\xamarin.visualstudio\Broker.zip' to '/tmp/Broker-16.8.000.260-2054e5d0-1d43-4a3a-bb31-ba1092028c66'
```

[image: Error in Pair to Mac Window]

[image: Visual studio log shows scp file transfer error because Client not connected]

Thanks! -Matt

Comment: Hi, do you mean when opening the window of **Pair to Mac** then occur this error?

Comment: No, @Junior, I press add Mac, type IP, username and password, wait while it checks Mono and Xamarin.iOS on the Mac, then it fails to install the Broker.

Comment: Okey, then you could have a check whether the version of VisualStudio and Xcode is the latest version.

Comment: Yes, I updated VS to the latest on Windows and it’s a brand new MacBook with the OS updated to the latest and a fresh install of the latest Xcode from the App Store.

Comment: Also, I let Visual Studio do the Mono and Xamarin.iOS installs on the Mac through SSH, then it failed to install the Broker with the error pictured. Now it never gets past that point failing with the same error every time. “Unable to copy file ‘c:\...\Broker.zip’ to ‘/tmp/...’”. I checked /tmp/ on the Mac and the file is transferred in part before the connection is severed every time. Exactly 16,384 bytes is transferred leaving the file incomplete.

Comment: Hi, why *let Visual Studio do the Mono and Xamarin.iOS installs on the Mac through SSH*? You'd better use visual studio installer to install them to check whether it works.